# How many unique values of quality are in this dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I need to answer this question: 
How many unique values of quality are in this dataset?

I tried out to answer this question with this function:
df.pd.groupby('quality').unique()

[image]

However, there is a mistake. 
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the number of unique items in a `pandas` series (column), you should use [`pd.Series.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
res = df['quality'].nunique()
```

Your code does not work because `pd` is not an *attribute* of your dataframe. It is in fact, a reference to a library. You might find `import pandas as pd` near the beginning of your code.

Comment: actually I did import pandas. However, if I put you code into jupyter I have no output

Comment: @DilyanaFlower, Sorry, I don't understand the problem. Does `df['quality'].nunique()` not give the answer you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect way to extract it. Pandas has a function called `value_counts()`, which extracts the unique values with its number of times repeated.
To use it is `df.colName.value_counts()`.
An example of code could be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
TableWithCounter = df.a.value_counts()
```

Once this is done, one can just use `index` to extract the list unique items as `TableWithCounter.index`

Comment: `value_counts` gives a count of each value. Although you can derive a solution, it doesn't directly answer `How many unique values`.

Comment: You are totally right. It requires an extra step, though it gives extra rellevant info about the distribution of your unique values